# Do we really need to pass the adapter layout to an array adapter twice?

Tags: android

So far, a common pattern that I noticed in implementing an Array Adapter is to pass the layout twice to the adapter (in the constructor and in the getView) like this:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    MyAdapter(){
        super(cxt, R.layout.adapter_layout);
    }

    getView(...){
        convertView = inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, ...);
    }

}
```

But is it really necessary?

Comment: if you are handling getView on your own you can pass whatever value you like to the super constructor.

Comment: it takes an int. You have to pass an int.

Comment: Just make sure you don't call `super.getView()` if you pass an invalid layout ID to the `super` constructor.

Comment: I'll try it (although I think I tried this months ago when I just started learning android but it somehow led to some error).